# How to include socket.io with angularjs and Express.js?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, socket.io

Using socket.io with nodejs and angular

```
myApp.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

'io' not defined error

In express i'm writing:-

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(app.get('port')));
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('io.socket connection');
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

The server is not showing error.

I am trying to follow [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socket-io-and-expressjs/) tutorial.

Edit:- 
when i add `<script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>`

it says `connect` is not a method of object 'io'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket.io is meant to be installed both on the server and on the client. By calling `require()` on the server you use the server-side library, but you still need to include the client-side library in the browser.

Put this somewhere in your HTML file ([CDN provided by Cloudflare](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io/)):

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

Note this is detailed in the basic example on [the front page](http://socket.io/) of the Socket.io website.

Comment: thanks. now it says 'connect' is not method defined.

Comment: Looks like you're using an old version of Socket.io (0.6). See my updated answer, it uses the latest stable version (0.9.16).